# Shortcut key for archive and open next message

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

The `e` [shortcut key in GMail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en&ctx=mail&authuser=1) archives the current conversation:

```
e    Archive     Archive your conversation from any view.
```

In my personal GMail account, hitting `e` opens he next conversation automatically. In my corp account, `e` archives the conversation and returns to the inbox.

Any idea how to set the `e` key to archive and open the next conversation?

**Update: I do not have the `Auto-advance` option in my general settings:**
[image]

**Update #2: `Auto-advance` is enabled at the `labs` tab.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open *Settings* and choose **Go to next (newer) conversation** in *Auto-advance* section of General tab.

[image]

Comment: I did not have "Auto advance" in my general tab - had to enable it in the `labs` tab. Thanks!

Comment: I found it in the `Advanced` tab.

Comment: Google keeps moving things here and there. Feel free to update the answer with correct setting applicable as of today

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to change your settings (as @buddha suggests), you can also use the other shortcut (type '?' in Gmail to see this):

`}` :   Archive conversation and go to previous

`{` :   Archive conversation and go to next

From [Keyboard shortcuts for Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594)